# Get image height in IE of display:none image?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7

I have images who are set to `display:none`.  I am using javascript (`document.getElementById('elem').height`) to get the height/width of these images.

This works in other browsers, but IE reports the height to be 0 (presumably due to the fact that its display is set to none - because when I remove the display:none, the height is reported correctly). I tried wrapping the images in a div and setting the div's display to none instead of the images - but this didn't work either.

What is the typical work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Position it offscreen
2. set it to display:block
3. get its height
4. set it back to display:none
5. re-position it back where it was

Answer (score 9):

If you are interested in the size of the image itself, apart from any styles or attributes set in the html, you can measure a new Image with the same src.

It doesn't add anything to the document's html or stylesheets, or even to document.images.length if you are only testing included images.

```
var  im=new Image();
im.src=element.src;
return [im.src,  im.width, im.height];
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use `visibility: hidden;`, maybe in combination with `position:absolute` too prevent "flickering" which you will remove after reading out the height.

Answer (score 0):

`display:none;` elements are defined as not having any display properties, so height and width shouldn't be used while it's in this state.

You could try setting it to `visibility:hidden;`, which would retain height and width. The downside of this is that `visibility` doesn't affect it's position in the page flow, so it will also retain the space it takes up in the layout. You could counter-act that by setting the `position` to either `absolute` or `fixed` to take it out of the context flow. You may also want to set the `z-index` to a negative value to ensure it gets hidden behind the rest of the page elements, otherwise it might block other elements from being clicked, etc, even though it would be invisible.